# mysql error creating procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I don't know so mutch of mysql but i have errors and I don't know why. Here is the code:

```
USE MServers;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Init`
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `Init`()
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Users`;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Ranks`;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `PBattles`;
    CREATE TABLE `Users` (
        `ID` INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        PRIMARY KEY (`ID`), 
        UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`), 
        INDEX(`ID`), 
        `username` CHARACTER VARYING(30) NOT NULL, 
        `uuid` CHARACTER VARYING(36) NOT NULL, 
        `rank` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
    );
    CREATE TABLE `Ranks` (
        `ID` INT(1) NOT NULL, 
        UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`), 
        `rank` varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
        UNIQUE KEY `rank` (`rank`)
    );
    INSERT INTO `Ranks` (`id`, `rank`) 
            VALUES (0, 'default'), (1, 'Noble'), (2, 'Guerrero'), 
                    (3, 'King'), (4, 'Heroe'), (5, 'Mitico'), (6, 'Legendario'), 
                    (7, 'SemiDios'), (8, 'Dios'), (9, 'DCMaster'), 
                    (10, 'DCSupreme');

    CREATE TABLE `PBattles` (
        `ID` INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        PRIMARY KEY (`ID`), 
        UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`), 
        INDEX(`ID`), 
        `username` CHARACTER VARYING(30) NOT NULL, 
        `uuid` CHARACTER VARYING(36) NOT NULL);
END//
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: An `;` after `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS \`Init\`;` might help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like missed `//` in two places,

```
DELIMITER //
USE MServers //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Init` //

CREATE PROCEDURE `Init`()
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Users`;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Ranks`;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `PBattles`;
    CREATE TABLE `Users` (`ID` INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`ID`), UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`), INDEX(`ID`), `username` CHARACTER VARYING(30) NOT NULL, `uuid` CHARACTER VARYING(36) NOT NULL, `rank` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0');
    CREATE TABLE `Ranks` (`ID` INT(1) NOT NULL, UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`), `rank` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, UNIQUE KEY `rank` (`rank`));
    INSERT INTO `Ranks` (`id`, `rank`) VALUES (0, 'default'), (1, 'Noble'), (2, 'Guerrero'), (3, 'King'), (4, 'Heroe'), (5, 'Mitico'), (6, 'Legendario'), (7, 'SemiDios'), (8, 'Dios'), (9, 'DCMaster'), (10, 'DCSupreme');
    CREATE TABLE `PBattles` (`ID` INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`ID`), UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`), INDEX(`ID`), `username` CHARACTER VARYING(30) NOT NULL, `uuid` CHARACTER VARYING(36) NOT NULL);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

See procedure syntax here - http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx

may this will help you

Comment: that work, a lot of thans!!!

Comment: welcome @esquerbatua  :)